# Find the minimum threshold (cdf)

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

> What is the threshold GPA such that at most 2% of the students achieve
>   a GPA larger than that threshold?
>
> Formally we ask: find the minimum value of $x_0$ such that
>
> $Pr(X \gt x_0) \leq .02 = $
>
> $Pr(X \leq x_0) \geq .98 = $
>
> $F(x_0) \geq .98$

I don't understand how both the probabilities are simultaneously using their $\ge$, $\leq$ counterparts for $.02$ and $.98$ but not in the parameters of the probability (with $x_0$). Wouldn't this be overcounting because the first probability does not include $x_0$ and the second probability does, but both probabilities are using $\leq$ and $\ge$ instead of $\leq$ and $\gt$ or $\lt$ and $\ge$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no over counting. Think about it, if $Pr(X>x_0)=0.02$ then what will be the value of $Pr(X\leq x_0)$ ?